# Syndrome Leaders

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

I've been stuck on this problem for a long time and I can't figure it out. I need to find the set of coset leaders and their syndromes. I have my coset leaders (I think) but I can't figure out how to find their syndromes. Can someone help me understand what their syndromes are and how to find them? Thanks!

Comment: All vectors in a coset have the _same_ syndrome. If $\mathbf x$ is a vector in the coset, then the syndrome (of the coset) is $H\mathbf x^T$ where $H$ is the parity check matrix of the code.

Comment: My parity matrix is:
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\\end{pmatrix}

This is my coset/syndrome table:

Coset: 00000|10000|01000|00100|00010|00001|11000|10001
Syn:    000 | 111 | 001 | 011 | 001 | 100 | 110 | 010

I noticed that the syndrome 001 is in there twice - is that ok?

Comment: You need to hit the books again. Your understanding of what a coset is and what is its syndrome seems to be quite different from what other people mean by the terms.

Comment: I'm reading from the Introduction to the Theory of Error-Correcting Codes: Vera Pless (which is not helpful at all) and following this pdf: http://www.ms.uky.edu/~corso/teaching/math362/coding-theory-2.pdf

Also note that those should be the coset leaders*

Comment: Something doesn't add up. Check the parity check matrix. If the second and fourth columns really are identical, then the code has minimum distance two only. It would also imply that $01000$ and $00010$ belong to the same coset so they cannot both appear in the coset leader table. And, NO! It is not ok for two leaders to have the same syndrome. That means that they are in the same coset.